How to move (MoveByTransporter) multiple agent by one transporter?
I'm creating a bicycle factory simulation, where I've set up a source that generates 5 agents, and as they are processed(sink), 5 agents are simultaneously generated in source:frame1_5. I want to know if I can use a transporter fleet where a single forklift can transport these 5 agents at once to a pallet Rack and store them there. enter image description here
I don't know how to set the number of agents that one transporter can carry at a time

A transporter can pick only one agent. Based on what you described, you should have a second type of agent BikeBatch or something similar, and use the Batch block. This way, your bikes will become one BikeBatch, and be transported. At the other side, you can Unbatch to retrieve the original Bike agents.

Thank you so much! I changed logic like [frame1_5(source) - batch - seizeTransporter - loading(delay) - toStorage1(moveByTransport) - unbatch - rackStore - releaseTransporter - sink] .  After doing this and running the simulation, I get the error : root.seizeTransporter:
Agent '28' should be located in space.
Do you know how to fix this error?

pls always open new issues for new questions, SOF does not work like a forum. See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
